# Git: remember SSH user and password temporarily without SSH keys

Tags: git, unix, ssh

Is there any way how to temporarily store my SSH login data (= username and password) when working with more git commands? For example, "git submodule update ..." asks for a password twice, so it is horrible when I call this command several times.

When we install our software on customer's server, we have script that automates everything (pulls from our git repository, updates submodules, configures etc.), so login data must be stored during the installation procedure only.

Generating and storing SSH keys is not solution for my problem, username + password must be used and it must not be saved at the server (only temporarily in memory). Storing git repository URL is ok, but it is not possible to store ssh://username@server!

Comment: Why can't you use keys? If I were allowing a third party access to my server, I would *much* rather keys be used than password authentication. Then `ssh-agent` would be the solution to your problem.

Comment: I guess that using SSH keys requires me to generate a key on my server, then copy it to the customer's server and then delete it after the procedure is done. And repeat this on every SW update and it is not the solution... the only solution is to execute script and enter login+password without generating and copying some keys.

Comment: Why would you delete the public key from the user's server? You can reuse the same pair for each update, unless you yourself are not guarding the private key sufficiently.

Comment: Password authentication is for *people*, not scripts.

Comment: Maybe, I just don't understand the point of the key properly, but if I leave it on customer's server, doesn't it mean that he can now use it for any other SSH connection to my server? ... and I already use such SSH key to connect from my PC to our server and every time the server's password changes, I must regenerate new SSH key.

Comment: No, the keys are asymmetric. Using your private key, you can log into a server containing the corresponding public key, but they cannot log into your server using the public key.

Comment: If you have to regenerate a key when the password changes, something is horribly misconfigured. Public key authentication works even if password authentication is disabled.

Comment: Now I don't understand you. If I store my key to customer's server so I can make passwordless connection from customer's server to my server, then customer can connect to my server too.

Comment: Why are you connecting from the customer to your server? I thought you were pushing updates *to* the customer from your server. Giving your customer access to your machine, no matter how briefly, is *completely* broken. (That said, you can configure `sshd` to limit what commands can be executed by someone authenticating with a particular key, if there is no way to avoid that.)

Comment: You can also use connection multiplexing (see `man ssh_config`, under the `ControlMaster` option) to create a single authenticated connection that other `ssh` commands can piggyback off of without re-authenticating.

Comment: It is not important. Connection is always done from customer's server to my server and this cannot be changed. That's why I want to avoid generating and storing SSH keys and use login+password only.

Comment: Thank you, ControlMaster (+other) option seems to do what I need - remember SSH connection for specified amount of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

SSH keys are neither users nor passwords, so that this question does not make sense.  An SSH key consists of pair of data files that you generate (typically using `ssh-keygen` though the precise command is irrelevant—what matters is the data in the pair of files).

The pair itself consists of:

- a *public key*, which you hand to other entities—other computers, other organizations, individual people, whoever you like, without fear that they will pass it on; and
- a *private* key.

The reason you have no fear of the public key being [bruited-about](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bruited) is that the public key is not really a *key* at all, not in the sense of physical keys that open doors.  Instead, it's more like the *key-hole* into which *you* can insert your actual key—your private key.  If you give your public key to Joe, and Joe gives your public key to Katie, this means that you can now walk into Joe's and Katie's homes, but *neither* Joe *nor* Katie can walk into yours.  Or, as [chepner put it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54669820/git-remember-ssh-user-and-password-temporarily-without-ssh-keys#comment96130892_54669820), the keys are asymmetric.

In other words, the *private* key is the one you should be careful with.  It's the actual key.  The *public* key is the access.  If you intend to let the customer log in from their end to your site, you might have the *customer* generate the key-pair.  Then *you* would install—at least briefly—the public-key at your site.  From that point on, the customer can gain access to your system.  As soon as you suspect the customer of mis-using their (private) key, or no longer want them to access your system, you would *remove* the public-key from your system.  Their private key continues to "open the lock" identified by that public-key, but since that lock is not one of the locks on *your* door, that no longer matters.